# How can use DES encryption algorithm on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

DES class is not support WP8, is there have some alternative solution or 3rd part libirary on windows phone 8 platform?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.security.cryptography.des.aspx

Consider to our bussiness, we can't use other encryption algorithm, and that also we need a high performance DES algorithm to encrypting a 1M file quickly, Anybody know?

Many Thanks~

Comment: DES is probably not supported because it is not secure by today's standards. Use a better encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [C# version of Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) that can be compiled for Windows Phone and supports DES.

Be aware of the limitations of DES encryption though and how its key size means it is no longer considered secure.